# Why did the Voleth Meir appear in dreams of these people?

Tags: the-witcher

In *The Witcher*, season 2, Voleth Meir or the deathless mother appeared in the dream of only three people, Francesca Findabair, Fringilla Vigo, and Yennefer of Vengerberg. Why did she appear in the dreams of only these three people?

Comment: I think it’s worth noting that just because we only see her in the dreams of 3 people doesn’t mean she only appeared to those people. It’s just that they’re the only people the season focuses on who Voleth Meir happens to appear to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Voleth Meir has not been active the whole time since she was imprisoned all those years ago by the first witchers. She only awoke when Ciri screamed at Cintra and broke the Monolith.

> **Ciri:** My scream woke Voleth Meir.
>
> <sub>*The Witcher*, Season 2 Episode 8, "Family"</sub>

We then know that she only appeared to these 3, who are all mages, when they were nearing a location that led them to her. She brought the 3 of them together through the shared dreams and they then discovered her within the temple.

> **Yennefer:** It's Elder speech, but primitive. "Behold the mother of forests, the deathless mother, nesting in dreams." The rest is gibberish.
>
> No. It's an incantation.
>
> [...]
>
> **Voleth Meir:** Turn your back to the forest.
>
> She's calling us.
>
> <sub>*The Witcher*, Season 2 Episode 2, "Kaer Morhen"</sub>

From the above we can speculate that she only appears to these 3 because of who they are and because they have the ability to get to her. We also know that all 3 suffer with a great deal of pain which Voleth Meir can use to get powerful enough to escape.

Lastly, I'll note that just because she is only shown to appear to these three doesn't mean that she only appears to these three. It's just that they're the only three that we're following who she appears too. She's not exactly going to appear to a witcher or Ciri and give her presence away. No one else is really a main enough character that we follow who she would appear to except maybe Jasker.

Answer (score 0):

Voleth Meir doesn't appear in canon, so it is hard to answer the question unless someone can find a quote by the director or such.

It has been noted that the character seems very much inspired by Slavic folk lore, where the witch [Baba Yaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baba_Yaga) lives in a hut on legs. This witch is in some versions of the myth presented as three identical sisters, which could explain why the script writer decided to let three sorceresses get her visions.

A lot of the material of season 2 in the show is not canon. For example, in canon this is what actually happens during the Battle of Sodden Hill:

- Francesca is a member of the Brotherhood and fights against Nilfgaard at Sodden Hill. She remains loyal to the Brotherhood until later on in the story. She never gets pregnant nor have a romantic relation with Filavandrel.
- Fringilla fights for Nilfgaard like in the show, but not because she is a royal advisor but since it is her homeland - she's from somewhere around Toussaint.
- During the battle, Fringilla magically blinds Yennefer. Yennefer does *not* lose her powers though. Her sight is later restored.

So it wouldn't make much sense for any of the three sorceresses to make a deal with the witch like in the show.

Furthermore in canon, it is actually Triss who everyone think died and who get her named carved on the memorial as "Fourteenth of the Hill". In the show they switched this with Yennefer.

Comment: You specify a lot "in canon" but the show is it's own canon, it can have an answer within itself. And, to be honest, I'm not really seeing how a lot of this answers the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot We treat any other work of fiction similarly so I don't see why this would be different. If specifically interested in the show, then maybe a tag should be for that, like for example [tag:game-of-thrones]. Anyway, I think it is unfair that an unanswerable question gets up-voted while an attempt to answer it with sources and actual references to the actual books gets down-voted. How else would we answer this if the show "is its own canon" - it would mean that the only way to answer any question would be to go watch the show. Should I post an answer "go watch the show and see"?

Comment: The question is about the show and a character that doesn't appear in the books. It's certainly not an unanswerable question. Game of Thrones is a good example here. The show and the books diverge enough that they are their own canons each but are similar enough that one may use either one to backup an answer for the other media etc. However, when asking about something specific to one canon/media only it doesn't make much sense to post an answer which is essentially "it doesn't happen in the other media".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot So a valid question for this site is "Does Voleth Meir like puppies?" There is no evidence or material available to answer that question either. But it should be up-voted for being a great answerable question, yeah?

Comment: It's a valid question, sure. Is it a good question? That's subjective but I imagine most would say no. It's also not really analogous to this question either. I will note though that just because you're aware of no evidence for _this_ question doesn't mean there isn't any. I've been forming an answer for it myself but it's not quite there yet.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Anyway I think this is all quite ridiculous since The Witcher - unlike many other works of fantasy - has a well-defined canon established by the author, who is alive and well (and has the copyright). Canon according to Sapkowski are the short stories and books written by him. There are several interviews where he denies that various shows and games are canon, but separate works of fiction. Furthermore the games are much more closer to this canon than the Netflix TV show, so in that context it already makes perfect sense to speak about canon before this show was even made.

Comment: I think you've just proven my point that answering with "this doesn't happen in the books" doesn't help answering a show question since they are "separate works of fiction". However, I'll leave this here.